# Решение задачи с помощью машинного обучения

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Начал заниматься программированием совсем недавно, конкретно машинным обучением. Возникла практическая задача, решить которую, с моим небольшим опытом, никак не получается. 
Имеется таблица данных с режимами обработки, выходным параметром которой является Z. Экспериментально было испытано n различных режимов обработки, по которым получено n выходных параметров Z. Возможно ли составить модель, которая на основе этого датасета сможет предсказать какие режимы необходимо применять (в заданных пределах amin - amax) для того, чтобы получить Zmax, Zmin. Также, возможно ли по данной модели предсказывать параметр Z, вводя параметры режима с клавиатуры?

И если все же это возможно, то в какую область мне нужно смотреть, что изучить для решения задачи?

Заранее, огромное спасибо, это мой первый вопрос тут!

Пример датасета:
[image]

Comment: почитайте о построении и использовании регрессионных моделей: линейеая регрессия, Ridge, Lasso, Least Angle Regression, SVM, Random Forest Regression, Нейронные Сети, etc.

Comment: Читайте про регрессию первым делом, без этого базиса никак

Comment: Большое всем спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Вы же пишете, что "Начал заниматься .... конкретно машинным обучением". Это значит, что данную задачу вам не начальство сбросило, и не на улице вас осенило -  "а давай-ка я посмотрю, что там с режимами обработки происходит" Скорее всего вы читали учебник или сидели на лекции (и спали) когда вам рассказывали, как такие задачи читать.

Но! .... Только потому, что это ваш первый вопрос тут.....

Теория:

[http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Многомерная_линейная_регрессия](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F)

http://statsoft.ru/home/textbook/modules/stmulreg.html

Практика (на Python, вы же еще и программирование начали изучать):

https://habr.com/ru/post/206306/

https://nagornyy.me/courses/data-science/regression/

[https://overcoder.net/q/61691/множественная-линейная-регрессия-в-python](https://overcoder.net/q/61691/%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-python)

https://www.machinelearningmastery.ru/simple-and-multiple-linear-regression-in-python-c928425168f9/

Изучайте.

Comment: Не начальство, пытаюсь совместить приятное с полезным) На самом деле пока только изучаю numpy, pandas, не хочу дальше лезть не ознакомившись с основами (как мне пояснили) И огромное Вам спасибо за ссылки!)

Answer (score 0):

Всё возможно. Я сам новичёк и мало чего знаю. Но могу сказать точно что нужно понять как преобразуются эти числа в вывод Z, и если вводить значения чисел A,B,C,D,E и F то сделать это будет на много проще, замечая как значения Z *будут менятся в зависимости от ввода.*

Comment: Вы увидели ответ?

Comment: Да, спасибо большое)